# What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$ equal to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So we know that 
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1
$$

Is there any information on what

$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}
$$
equals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's interesting to see that sums like this are described by the [Jacobi theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html). Recalling that we have $$\theta_{3}\left(q\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}},\,\left|q\right|<1$$ in our case we have, by symmetry, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n^{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n^{2}}}-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\theta_{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\approx0.56445.$$

Comment: @Wojowu Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Try writing out the first few partial sums in base 2 . . .

---

If you're not satisfied by this description of the result, note that it's not hard (EDIT: Whoops, this is bonkers! Hey, it was late, I was tired. :P See below.) to show that the number is transcendental, ruling out any nice description in terms of polynomials. With more effort you can rule out other nice kinds of description. I don't think this number does have a snappy description, other than the above.

Comment: By the way, my postscript assumes that you mean "$1\over 2^{(n^2)}$" and not "$1\over (2^n)^2$". The latter, of course, is rational (exercise - what is it?).

Comment: "It's not hard to show that the number is transcendental." Given that transcendentals weren't always known to exist, and that the first example of one needed factorials in the exponent, I doubt that it's "not hard to show"…

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The proof of transcendence of this number is truly marvelous, but the comment box is too small to contain it!

Comment: In particular this is **not** covered by the Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem: the approximation of the sum by the $n$'th partial sum has denominator $d = 2^{n^2}$ and error $\sim 2^{-(n+1)^2} > d^{-2}$, much too big to conclude anything.

Comment: However, Google turns up [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to).  So it is transcendental, but not easy.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this number expressible in terms of one of the [theta funcitons](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

$$
\vartheta_3(0,1/2)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}\text{.}
$$

So your number is $$\frac{\vartheta_3(0,1/2)-1}{2}\text{.}$$

Comment: It's identical to my answer.